# sortables in tabs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs, jquery-ui-sortable

**EDIT 1:**

You can try this by removing the sortable script from the link below.  As soon as you remove it, the tabs start working.

**ORIGINAL QUESITON:**

I have the following script:

http://jsfiddle.net/oshirowanen/mYx5y/

It consists of tabs and sortables.

For some reason, as soon as I add the sortable script, the tabs stop working.  Why is this happening?  Along side that, the sortables don't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code had a lot of errors (extra brackets). I fixed them and it works now : http://jsfiddle.net/bs2VV/

**EDIT** code follows

```
$("#tabs").tabs();

$(".column").sortable({
    connectWith: '.column',
    update: function(event, ui) {
        alert($(this).closest("div").attr("id"));
        alert($(this).sortable('serialize', {
            key: 'item'
        }));
    }
});

$(".column").disableSelection();
```

Comment: you should put the answer on here as well lol just in case people click on it at a later date and don't know what you two are on about :) when you get a different code all together as links could be temporary there :)